# How can I add 2 spaces to a block of code (indentation)?

Tags: html, notepad++, indentation

I'm coding HTML in Notepad++. I want to Indent a block of code. I dislike the `tab` indentation and want to use 2 spaces instead. How can I add 2 spaces before a block of selected text/code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings > Preferences...
Tab Settings.
Change the tab size from 4 to 2.
Check the "replace by space".
Either do that globally, or for the file extension you want it to apply to.